# How can I retrieve the baseFeePerGas value for historical blocks on Astar?

Tags: evm, astar, fee, gas

I want to calculate fees for historical EIP-1559 transactions on Astar EVM. For this, I need to use the `GasPrice` formula:

```
GasPrice = BaseFee + MaxPriorityFeePerGas < MaxFeePerGas ? 
        BaseFee + MaxPriorityFeePerGas : 
        MaxFeePerGas;
```

`MaxPriorityFeePerGas` and `MaxFeePerGas` values are available in transaction data and are set by the user but `BaseFee` value is not. As far as I know this value is set by the system and is dynamic. Is there a way to retrieve this `BaseFee` value for historical blocks? Is this information stored in the blockchain and can it be read directly?

**Solution:**

In order to get `baseFee` value using the Ethereum API see [@gluneau](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/users/712/gluneau) answer.

When it comes to the Substrate API:
In the Astar blockchain, there exists a `BaseFee` pallet, which stores the `baseFee` value for each block. We can access its storage to fetch the `baseFee` value for any specific block.

For instance, with the Substrate Sidecar API, we can use the following path to obtain the `baseFeePerGas` value for block number 1300000:

```
/pallets/base-fee/storage/BaseFeePerGas?at=1300000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a method to get historical `baseFeePerGas`

```
const { ethers } = require("ethers");

async function getBaseFee(blockNumber) {
    const rpc = "https://evm.astar.network"
    let provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(rpc);
    let block = await provider.getBlock(blockNumber);
    return block.baseFeePerGas;
}

let blockNumber = 1300000;  // replace with the block number you're interested in
getBaseFee(blockNumber)
    .then(baseFee => console.log(`Base fee for block ${blockNumber}: ${baseFee}`))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

I've made also a [replit you can play with](https://replit.com/@gluneau/Get-get-base-fee-price-per-gas-from-Astars-EVM?v=1).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. While your suggestion to use the Ethereum API to fetch the base fee is valid, I was specifically interested in achieving the same via the Substrate API. After doing some additional research, I have found the answer. I will update my question with the solution.